# How to add two variables together in PHP?

Tags: php

I'm currently trying to put two variables together, one that has already a specific number automatically calculated by `imagesy` and the second variable is returning data from url with `$_GET['l2_y']`

```
imagettfstroketext($jpg_image, 0, $y . $options['text']['font-position']['l2_y'] );
```

The $y returns `'29'`

and the `$options['text']['font-position']['l2_y']` returns `+150` (or whatever I set in the header)

I am trying to combine the two but it's not working at all, if I remove the `$y .` then the +150 works but if I add the . it doesn't calculate everything..

I've been stuck at this for a while now, I'm not sure how to combine the two, the reason I am using + signs in get is because it can also be used as a `-150` to change the position of the text.

Comment: Combining as is adding the two numbers up?

Comment: How about something like `intval($y) + intval($options['text']['font-position']['l2_y'])` to coerce both to numbers (they might be strings now) and then simply use mathematics (and not the `.` concatenation)?

Comment: @somethinghere that's actually perfect, if you'd like to add that as the answer I'd appreciate it.

Comment: I've added it as an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try to coerce both numbers to integers using `intval` and then add them (using `+` and not `.`, which is used for concatenating strings):

```
intval($y) + intval($options['text']['font-position']['l2_y'])
```

That way you are sure both are numbers before you add them (so you avoid any unwanted results).

However, it is not *necessary* to coerce them into integers if you simply use the `+` (adding) operator and not the `.` concatenation operator, as the following works as well:

```
echo '+2' + 3; // outputs 5
```

PHP automatically coerces numbers, `intval` is useful if you want to be sure it is a number (usually when somebody inputs a number into your site).

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
<?php
    $var1 = '1';
    $var2 = '+1';
    $var3 = '-1';
    
    echo $var1 + $var2; //2
    echo $var1 + $var3; //0
?>
```

Comment: Why should the OP try this? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: You are right but I think in here it is so easy to understand .. here the code explains itself ... if you try to explain some thing so simple i think it will look complex

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be using the `.` operator, this will concatenate the values as if they were strings. The correct way to do this would require the use of `+`.

For example: `imagettfstroketext($jpg_image, 0, $y + $options['text']['font-position']['l2_y'] );` assuming that `$y` is a number and not a string.

Using the values you have, this will return the number 179, whereas the version using the `.` operator will return a **string** which contains the value `"29150"`

If the values are not numbers and are in fact strings, you can also encapsulate each variable in an `intval($var)` which will take the integer value of the variable if it exists.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're after:

```
imagettfstroketext($jpg_image, 0, intval($y) + intval($options['text']['font-position']['l2_y']));
```

`.` is for strings, `+` is for numbers. In case `$y` and/or `$options['text']['font-position']['l2_y']` are strings (which they are if they have quotes around them), cast them to integers with `intval()`. PHP will interpret `+150` as 150 and `-150` as -150

Comment: Please do not ask questions in answers.

Comment: I changed it but out of curiosity; why?

Comment: Because an answer is not designed to be a question, especially if the question is overly broad. Stack Overflow is designed to be a question/answer site. The OP asks the question, others answer. If you need to ask a clarification question you should ask it in comments.

Comment: @JayBlanchard It was intended to convey my doubt as to whether or not it could really be so simple (I rarely give a one line answer). Anyway, no biggie. "I think" is an adequate substitute... I think :)